# My function to remove duplicates is not working, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

//This is the email list

var emailList =["adam@yahoo.edu\n", "henry@yahoo.edu\n", "john@yahoo.edu\n", "sally@yahoo.edu\n", "adam@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "myhome@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "hunger@yahoo.edu\n", "madison@yahoo.edu\n", ];

//I am removing @yahoo.edu

function removeAddress(list){
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = list[i].replace("@yahoo.edu", " ");
    }
}

//Function to remove the duplicates in the list

function removeDuplicates(list)
{
    var hash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        var array = list[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) 
        {
            var val = array[j];
            var hashedVal = hash[val];
            if (hashedVal === undefined) 
            {
                hash[val] = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                array.splice(j, 1);
                if (array.length == 0)
                {
                    list.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = emailList;
//Remove @yahoo.edu from the list

removeAddress(emailList);

//Sort the list

emailList.sort();

//Remove the duplicates

removeDuplicates(emailList);

//Print the list

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = emailList;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem description. What your function does instead? It does nothing? It creates more duplicates? It throws stones to neighbours' windows? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @TeemuI am new to Javascript. My function, removeDuplicates, when called does not remove the duplicates from my list.  I am using Tryit Editor v2.5. I am not getting an error, persae, my program doesnt run.

Comment: There are a number of third-party libraries that have a function to do this. For instance, jQuery has `$.unique`, Underscore has `_.uniq`.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I'm not sure why you're traversing a 1 dimensional array with 2 loops. That's not necessary. Secondly, you're iterating through the array while also removing elements. When the element is removed, all elements after it are pushed forwards 1 index. Then `i` is incremented, causing you to miss an item. If you want to continue with the `for` loop and using `.splice()`, you need to manually decrement `i` when you remove an item. Also, you only need one loop since `emailList` is an array of strings.

```
function removeDuplicates(list)
{
  var hash = {};
  var newList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
  {
    var email = list[i];
    if (hash[email] === undefined) {
      hash[email] = true;
    } else {
      list.splice(i, 1);
      i --;
    }
  }
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyKJOP

Answer (score 1):

In the inner `for`, you are looping a string, not another array. 
Second, you may want to `.join()` the array at the end to obtain a printable string.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially, you're just getting a list of user names. It could have been simplified to the following:

```js
var emailList = ["adam@yahoo.edu\n", "henry@yahoo.edu\n", "john@yahoo.edu\n", "sally@yahoo.edu\n", "adam@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "myhome@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "hunger@yahoo.edu\n", "madison@yahoo.edu\n"];

var usernameHash = emailList.reduce(function(usernames, email, i) {
  var username = email.slice(0, email.indexOf('@'));
  if(!usernames[username]) usernames[username] = true;
  return usernames;
}, {});

var usernames = Object.keys(usernameHash)

document.write(usernames.join(', '));
```

Comment: Searching the list in the filter makes this O(n^2). The hash method is O(n). Although if the list is small it's probably not a big deal.